# How to print specific MySQL Error information on Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, runtime-error

I've managed to connect to my MySQL database through Java, and now I'm experimenting with Querys and Insertions, the only problem is the debugging part.
At most, when an error occurs, through Try-Catch I'm able to print a basic message such as:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO NAVE(ID,QPersone,QMerci), VALUES('C1','100','1000')' at line 1.
```

with the instruction `e.printStackTrace()` where `e` is the captured Exception.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");  
        String username = "...";
        String password = "...";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", username, password);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        try {
            String selQ = "SELECT * FROM NAVE";
            String insQ = "INSERT INTO NAVE(ID,QPersone,QMerci), VALUES('C1','100','1000')";
            stmt.execute(selQ+"; "+insQ);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Are there more specific Exceptions that I can include in `catch` or other ways to get a clearer error message?

P.s.
The error is that there is no table "Nave" in my database, which I wish the Console told me.

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) will let you test out your queries, while it doesn't explicitly correct syntax etc. per se it does let you play around with the script and will definitely let you know if things are working or not.

Comment: @Daschi Thank you a lot for the link, it will definetly work as a portable SQL query tester! But still, I wish there was someway to have the error shown from Java.